# Abrir archivo siempre abre con PDF

Tags: android, android-intent

Hola chicos y chicas (por supuesto)

Tengo este método para abrir un archivo

```
public static void openFile(String filePath, Activity activity) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://"+filePath));
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error abriendo."+filePath+" Abrir manualmente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

pero cuando establesco el camino a mi archivo por ejemplo image.jpg q esta en mi sdcard, simpre trata de abrirlo con el PDF-Drive, y por supuesto este da error al tratar de abrir este archivo. Pero cuando abro esta imagen desde el explorador de carpetas, me abre con el visor por defecto de imagenes.
Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trate de compilar en java (NetBeans) una lib.jar pero al importarla al projecto de android me decia que no encontraba la clase Path y lo demas que me daba error

Resolvi creando mi propia getMimeType

En 
https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/
encontre una lista bastante completa

Hice un

```
HashMap <String, String> ~ <ext, mime>
```

y para obtener el mime al hash que contiene todos le pido me de el valor de la extención

```
map.get(".bmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba añadiendo un intent.setType("image/jpeg") para establecer el tipo de archivo que desas abrir. Te dejo un enlace a la documentacion con varios ejemplos para enviar archivos y datos entre apps.

```
public static void openFile(String filePath, Activity activity) {
    try {
        Path path = new Paths.get(filePath);
        String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(path);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://"+filePath));
        intent.setType(mimeType);
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error abriendo."+filePath+" Abrir manualmente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

http://www.javacodex.com/Files/Determine-MIME-Type

Comment: gracias, pero no siempre es una imagen lo que abrira, digamos que la pregunta correcta seria **Como obtener el mimetype segun el archivo**.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es extraer la extension del nombre del archivo, y dependiendo de la extension usar un tipo u otro con condicionales.

Comment: He  añadido la funcion  Files.probeContentType que te devuelve el mimetype del archivo.

Comment: Mi clase Files no tiene ese metodo!??? o tengo la incorrecta https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B27bbyevIqeneDNiWV8tZUFlTHM y eso que le he puesto el import que aparece en el ejemplo

Comment: ya encontre el problema, importaba la case que no era , pues la otra como que la omite